# htaccess rewrite url: cannot find corresponding row in database anymore

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite my urls by replacing all spaces with a dash.

I got the following htaccess file so far:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\s|%20)
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+([^\s%20]+)((?:\s|%20)+.*)$ $1-$2$3 [N,DPI]
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [R=301,DPI]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^archive/([^/]+)$ news?title=$1

RewriteRule ^cars/([^/]+)$ carbrands?brand=$1
```

Assume that the title of an article in my database is "This is a test". Then with my htaccess file, the url that will be generated is:

```
example.com/archive/This-Is-A-Test
```

But it cannot find the corresponding article in my database cause it's looking for the title "This-Is-A-Test" instead of "This Is A Test".

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\s|%20)
RewriteRule ^(\S+)(?:\s|%20)+(\S+)((?:\s|%20)+.*)$ $1-$2$3 [N,DPI]
RewriteRule ^(\S+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [R=301,DPI]

RewriteRule ^archive/([^/]+)$ news?title=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^cars/([^/]+)$ carbrands?brand=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

And inside your `article.php` add this line at the stop:

```
$title = str_replace ('-', ' ', $_GET['title']);
```

Comment: Still a little problem here I'm afraid. It works perfectly until there's a number in the URL.

`example.com/archive/McLaren-MSO-650S%20Coupe%20Concept`

When I remove the "650" from the title in my database, it works again. `example.com/archive/McLaren-MSO-S-Coupe-Concept`.